How do I determine sample size for determining a trend over time?
I want to characterize how batteries degrade over time. Due to the chemicals within the batteries, they naturally decay, resulting in batteries having less energy over the years. I want to figure out what this decay looks like.
I have a ton of batteries produced from one lot. To figure out how much energy the batteries have, I need to perform a destructive test, so these batteries can only be sampled once. Also, due to their chemical nature, every battery is expected to be slightly different from the other batteries produced in the same lot.
I was planning on sampling maybe 15 batteries a month, every month, to figure out how the batteries' energy naturally go down over the years. However, I don't know how to mathematically calculate what a good monthly sampling amount should be for my purposes. Are there any methods out there that can be used for finding out the sample size to determine a trend?

Are you constrained by a budget?  Can you sample unlimited batteries per month and is the cost of the experiment per battery unit a factor in how you proceed with sampling?  Do you know what analytical approach you intend to use once you've determined the appropriate sample size?

I am heavily constrained by resources. The batteries we have are limited in supply, and the manufacturer can't provide more batteries than what they already provided. I have 500 total batteries that I would like to stretch over a span of 3 years, so I would be willing to change the rate from monthly to twice a year since I think you can still form a fairly decent trendline for my purposes with a not as good time resolution.

And for analytical approach, I was planning on doing a linear regression. The battery manufacturers give us linear rates of decay, so I can follow that model since it's the industry standard.

Although it's unclear what "linear rates of decay might mean," it's very likely the regression is not linear.  The information needed to develop reasonable answers to your question includes (a) the likely mathematical form of the decay function and (b) the expected degree of variation among the remaining batteries as a function of time.  You don't have to be perfectly correct with this information -- after all, it's what you're trying to find out! -- but without some reasonable guess, you can't even get started with an answer.

I can partially help, and will follow this question in hopes that someone will answer the other bit.
You say that you intend to keep the time between samples constant. I suspect that the decay is non-linear; probably some asymptote. There should be some literature somewhere on the shape of the decay curve. I suggest you re-write the equations to linearize the result, and use equal spacing on the linearized $x$-axis variable.
To explain this further: I have evaluated the progress of the front of the liquid in capillary action. The distance $d$ scales as $d = a\sqrt(t)+ b$. Measuring $d$ at equal intervals of time $t$ means that the data points “bunch up” in the left side of the trend. That makes the fit sensitive to spread in the data at long times. By taking constant intervals of $\sqrt(t)$ (and therefore unequal intervals of $t$) I got much more repeatable results.
The other part, I would love to see formalization. I usually see little benefit in repeat measurements; I notice that the regression takes care of a lot of noise. But, I might be mistaken about that.

This is a smart approach, I'd've never thought of this. Definitely will keep this info for future use in other studies. For this one though, the decay is fairly close to linear based on data sheets I've received and info online, so I don't think I will have to make many changes to the sampling intervals aside from possible alternating from monthly to some less frequent interval.
